# Making volume controller more fine

Tags: sony-xperia, volume-control

My Sony Xperia has buttons to control the volume as most of other smartphones. The control is rather coarse, there are only 8 steps including max volume and silence. Especially for use of (Bluetooth) headphones this is silly coarse.

How can the volume adjustment more fine? I would like to have e.g. 32 steps here.

**Edit:** The device isn't rooted and I don't plan to do so.

Comment: Depends on whether your device is rooted. If it is, and you've got the XPosed framework running: [XVolume](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.hansserver.xvolume) provides 30 steps, [VolumeSteps+](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.p1ngu1n.volumesteps) does something similar.

Answer (score -1):

No way to do so if your device isn't rooted.
Every app you find for the same will require root access.